# event sink for web browser in C++

Tags: visual-c++, com, browser

gud day!.

i am to develop a system that would simply list all URL accessed in a browser with its response time.
my probtion is alem is this applica standalone program(not a plug-in to a certain browser) written in c++. every time a user browse, the program then performs certain method.

so it is like, my program would listen to the browsers events. i dont know how to create an EVEN SINK implemetation for the above mention event in web browsers like Internet explorer, mozilla firefox and google chrome.

any suggestion, advise or idea i cant get from you for me to be able to start the development. any areas i need to focus in studying.

thanks alot for your time! hope for your response!:)

best regards!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve what you need is intercepting network traffic and extracting URLs from HTTP packets.
You can do this in many ways, e.g.:

- using WinPCAP/libPCAP libarary
- modifying LSP stack
- intercepting winsock functions calls

Answer (score 0):

If you're on the Windows platform, I think your best shot is using the MSAA interface, which is supported by all three browsers.

Documentation:

[MSDN Overview and C++ API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms697240%28VS.85,loband%29.aspx)

[Firefox statement of support for MSAA](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Accessibility/AT-APIs#AT_APIs_terms)

[Chrome](http://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/design-documents/accessibility#TOC-UI-Keyboard-Navigation)

You could take a lower-level approach (such as an LSP), but they're much harder to debug.